# udev rule to run Python script

Tags: python, pulseaudio, udev

I am trying to automatically run [this](https://gist.github.com/pylover/d68be364adac5f946887b85e6ed6e7ae#file-a2dp-py-L1) script, whenever I connect to my bluetooth headset.

I have created the file /etc/udev/rules.d/80-bt-headset.rules with the line

```
ACTION=="add", SUBSYSTEM=="input" ATTR{name}=="00:22:37:3D:DA:50" RUN+="/home/USER/.local/bin/a2dp.py 00:22:37:3D:DA:50"
```

but it doesn't do anything. The conditions are fine, a simple test comand is triggered when I enter that instead. The script itself also works fine when run manually.

What is going wrong here?

**Update**: There is an error when running the script with `sudo -u USER` (see below for details). Could this be the problem? And how does sudo-ing to the same user break things?

**Update 2**: After replacing all instances of `pacmd` with `pactl` in `a2dp.py` (and replacing `list-sinks` with `list sinks` to make it a valid pactl command), `sudo -u USER` works, however, the udev rule still doesn't. In `/var/log/syslog` I just see the line

```
systemd-udevd[32629]: Process '/home/USER/.local/bin/a2dp_2.py 00:22:37:3D:DA:50' failed with exit code 1.
```

**Update 3 (Solution)**: The modified skript (pacmd -> pactl, see Update 2) with the environment variables `DISPLAY=:0` and `XAUTHORITY=/home/USER/.Xauthority` did the trick. The udev rule:

```
ACTION=="add", SUBSYSTEM=="input" ATTR{name}=="00:22:37:3D:DA:50" ENV{DISPLAY}=":0" ENV{XAUTHORITY}="/home/USER/.Xauthority" RUN+="/home/USER/.local/bin/a2dp_2.py 00:22:37:3D:DA:50"
```

is working as intended.

(Now the only remaining problem is, that the script itself will trigger the rule, as it reconnects the headset, resulting in an infinite loop. However, that is a separate question, and it should not be too hard to find a workaround. In fact I was expecting that behaviour when I started this thread.)

### What works:

1. The conditions are fine: The line:

   ```
   ACTION=="add", SUBSYSTEM=="input" ATTR{name}=="00:22:37:3D:DA:50" RUN+="/bin/mkdir /tmp/testme"
   ```

   will create a new directory when I connect to the headset.
2. The script a2dp.py itself works fine when run from the terminal via

   ```
   /home/USER/.local/bin/a2dp.py 00:22:37:3D:DA:50
   ```
3. Running a simply Python script via udev:

   ```
   ACTION=="add", SUBSYSTEM=="input" ATTR{name}=="00:22:37:3D:DA:50" RUN+="/home/USER/.local/bin/atestscript.py"
   ```

   where atestscript.py contains:

   ```
   #!/usr/bin/python
   # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

   import subprocess

   def main():
       subprocess.Popen(['mkdir', '/tmp/atestdir'])

   if __name__ == '__main__':
       main()
   ```

   will again create a folder when the device is connected.

### What works after replacing pacmd with pactl:

4. Running the script from the terminal with `sudo -u USER` or even `sudo -u root` now works as intended
   (For the originial script this resulted in:

   ```
   USER@MACHINE:~$ sudo -u USER /usr/local/bin/a2dp.py 00:22:37:3D:DA:50
   Connection MADE
   Device MAC: 00:22:37:3D:DA:50
   Command: pacmd list-sinks failed with status: 1
   stderr: No PulseAudio daemon running, or not running as session daemon.

   Exiting bluetoothctl
   ```

### What does not work:

5. Running the script as above or with any of the following lines as the `RUN+=` part:

   ```
   /usr/bin/sudo -u USER /usr/bin/python3 /home/USER/.local/bin/a2dp.py 00:22:37:3D:DA:50
   /usr/bin/sudo -u USER /home/USER/.local/bin/a2dp.py 00:22:37:3D:DA:50
   /usr/bin/python3.5 /usr/local/bin/a2dp.py 00:22:37:3D:DA:50
   ENV{DISPLAY}=":0" RUN+="/usr/local/bin/a2dp.py 00:22:37:3D:DA:50"
   ```

   Even the modified script will not work:

   ```
   ENV{DISPLAY}=":0" ENV{PULSE_RUNTIME_PATH}="/run/user/1000/pulse/" RUN+="sudo -u USER /home/USER/.local/bin/a2dp_2.py 00:22:37:3D:DA:50"
   ```

**Further information:** udevadm monitor output on connecting to headset:

```
KERNEL[104388.664737] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-7/3-7:1.0/bluetooth/hci0/hci0:256 (bluetooth)
UDEV  [104388.667185] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-7/3-7:1.0/bluetooth/hci0/hci0:256 (bluetooth)
KERNEL[104390.848157] add      /devices/virtual/input/input46 (input)
UDEV  [104390.849150] add      /devices/virtual/input/input46 (input)
KERNEL[104390.849471] add      /devices/virtual/input/input46/event17 (input)
UDEV  [104390.864692] add      /devices/virtual/input/input46/event17 (input)
```

Comment: I don't think headsets belong to input subsystem. You also shouldn't run a script with Python interpreter as command and script as argument. Any valid reason for running it as USER ?  Run udev-monitor and try to connect the headset, see what the monitor displays

Comment: What I also get from the script is that it's supposed to have arguments. Your `RUN+=` part doesn't pass MAC address of the headset as argument to script, you just run the script alone.  See here for an example: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14982520/3701431

Comment: @SergiyKolodyazhnyy: The conditions should be fine. I have also added the 'udevadm monitor' output to the post (the udev-monitor command does not exist on my system). The interpreter as command and script as argument part is just me not knowing how to python; my bad. I tried running it as USER to get closer to what had worked before (me manually running the script as USER).

Comment: @SergiyKolodyazhnyy About the argument: The script works without an argument as long as only one bluetooth audio device has been paired with the system (if there are more, it will give you a choice when run in a terminal), but it is probably better to add the MAC address. I have tried adjusting the RUN+= part to reflect your suggestions (see edited post), but it still does not work.

Comment: @hife could check these: (1) `chmod +x /home/USER/.local/bin/a2dp.py` (2) parent folders permissions or change the script place (3) Call it with python `RUN+=/usr/bin/python3.5 ...`

Comment: @user.dz (1) is already set, (3) I have tried before without result, (2) I will try as soon as I can.

Comment: @user.dz No luck with (2) either. I have also tried running a simple python script, which works fine. So there seems to be something inside the script that is not getting what it needs (environment variables?).

Comment: Try `export DISPLAY=:0` it may be not enough for `pactl` used by that script. Look at this post answers, they contain some interesting env variables https://askubuntu.com/q/458194/26246 . otherwise search for `udev pactl`

Comment: @user.dz That looks promising and seems to explain the results of my testing (see edited post).  Can I just add environment variables via `DISPLAY=:0 /usr/bin/a2dp.py MAC`? As in: `sudo -u USER DISPLAY=:0 /usr/local/bin/a2dp.py MAC`? This sadly still yields the same error as before, but maybe I can find out more in the linked thread. Thank you very much for the effort so far.

Comment: @hife, I don't think udev RUN support that (I didn't see before in udev doc neither I  tried such thing, to be sure) . You may add `ENV{DISPLAY}=":0"`  before `RUN+=` , ref: http://www.reactivated.net/writing_udev_rules.html#env , or use another shell script to wrap the target python script.

Comment: @user.dz I found out that pactl was more stable than pacmd and the final missing variable was `XAUTHORITY` (I just added all variables that `printenv` showed in a normal user terminal to a wrapper script, saw that it worked, then repeatedly removed half the variables until it broke again, etc.; In hindsight, I could have guessed it.) Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### My working solution

1. Modify `a2dp.py` by replacing all instances of `pacmd` with `pactl` adjusting `pacmd list-sinks` to `pactl list sinks` (in my case saved as `/usr/local/bin/a2dp_2.sh`).
2. Create a wrapper script `/usr/local/bin/a2dp-wrapper.sh`

   ```
   #!/bin/bash

   MAC=$1
   MACMOD=$(echo $MAC | sed 's/:/_/g')

   PID=$(pgrep pulseaudio)
   USER=$(grep -z USER= /proc/$PID/environ | sed 's/.*=//')

   export DISPLAY=:0
   export XAUTHORITY=/home/$USER/.Xauthority

   if pactl list sinks short | grep "bluez_sink\.$MACMOD.*SUSPENDED" 
       then
       sudo -u $USER /usr/local/bin/a2dp_2.py $MAC
   fi
   ```
3. Add the following line to `/etc/udev/rules.d/80-bt-headset.rules`:

   ```
   ACTION=="add", SUBSYSTEM=="input" ATTR{name}=="00:22:37:3D:DA:50" RUN+="/usr/local/bin/a2dp-wrapper.sh $attr{name}"
   ```

This wrapper script accomplishes the following:

1. It finds out the `$USER` owning the running instance of pulseaudio, then sets the environment variables `DISPLAY=:0` and `XAUTHORITY=/home/$USER/.Xauthority` necessary for `pactl` to work. This should make it work for all users on a machine. (I have not tested the effects of multiple users logged in at the same time.)
2. It checks whether the corresponding sink is suspended and only then runs `a2dp_2.py`. This is necessary to prevent an infinite loop caused by `a2dp_2.py` reconnecting the device and thus triggering the rule.
3. It runs `a2dp_2.py` as $USER. If run as root, `a2dp_2.py` will leave pulseaudio, and thus any audio settings, inaccessible without root privileges.

### Alternatives: dbus loop/fixed package

1. An alternative solution using a dbus loop can be found on the [sript developer's page](https://gist.github.com/pylover/d68be364adac5f946887b85e6ed6e7ae#file-fix-bt-py).
2. A fix for the original bug is now available [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/pulseaudio/+bug/1582213/comments/8) and can be easily installed by adding `ppa:ubuntu-audio-dev/pulse-testing` and updating the available packages.

### Hint: Finding your device's MAC address

Not strictly part of the original problem, but this might be useful for future reference. There are numerous ways to find your device's MAC address. The following is the one I consider most helpful for udev rules:

1. Find the device path by running `udevadm monitor` and then connecting your device. Your output should look something like this:

   ```
   USER@MACHINE:~$ udevadm monitor
   monitor will print the received events for:
   UDEV - the event which udev sends out after rule processing
   KERNEL - the kernel uevent

   KERNEL[123043.617276] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-7/3-7:1.0/bluetooth/hci0/hci0:256 (bluetooth)
   UDEV  [123043.647291] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-7/3-7:1.0/bluetooth/hci0/hci0:256 (bluetooth)
   KERNEL[123044.153776] add      /devices/virtual/input/input68 (input)
   KERNEL[123044.153911] add      /devices/virtual/input/input68/event17 (input)
   UDEV  [123044.193415] add      /devices/virtual/input/input68 (input)
   UDEV  [123044.213213] add      /devices/virtual/input/input68/event17 (input)
   ```

   Stop the monitor with `Ctrl+C`. We have found three device paths. The one relevant for us is `/devices/virtual/input/input68`.
2. Plug the obtained path into `udevadm info`:

   ```
   USER@MACHINE:~$ udevadm info -a -p /devices/virtual/input/input68

   Udevadm info starts with the device specified by the devpath and then
   walks up the chain of parent devices. It prints for every device
   found, all possible attributes in the udev rules key format.
   A rule to match, can be composed by the attributes of the device
   and the attributes from one single parent device.

     looking at device '/devices/virtual/input/input68':
       KERNEL=="input68"
       SUBSYSTEM=="input"
       DRIVER==""
       ATTR{name}=="00:22:37:3D:DA:50"
       ATTR{phys}==""
       ATTR{properties}=="0"
       ATTR{uniq}==""
   ```

   We learn that the MAC address is `00:22:37:3D:DA:50` and also that it is stored as `ATTR{name}`.

Even if the output looks completely different, these two commands will be a good start in looking for the relevant conditions for a udev rule.

### Experimental: Catching arbitrary bluetooth audio devices

The rule:

```
ACTION=="add", SUBSYSTEM=="input" ATTR{name}=="??:??:??:??:??:??" RUN+="/usr/local/bin/a2dp-wrapper.sh $attr{name}"
```

will trigger for any input device that has a name attribute that looks like a MAC address and the conditional in the wrapper script should make sure no unintended actions are taken.

I do not have any other bluetooth audio device readily available to test this, but I see a number of potential issues:

1. This will only work for a bluetooth device that is recognised as an input device containing the MAC address in the name attribute. Not every device may be recognised as such.
2. This solution is not very elegant, as the rule will be triggered for any input device. However, I have not been able to find clear indicators to identify a bluetooth audio device. (As seen above, the input device has no further attributes, and the bluetooth device shows no indication of being an audio device, nor does it contain the MAC address. Maybe ACPI would be better for this.)
3. You may not want to treat every bluetooth audio device the same: You may want to use the HSP protocol for your headset or you may not want to automatically switch to your housemate's speakers, that you've paired with at some point, whenever they are available. In those cases it is probably preferable to have a separate rule for each device.

I will keep updating this post as I learn more.

Comment: For multi-user setup this answer https://askubuntu.com/a/642898/26246 has nice idea for getting the required env var from a running process. That question was about media player, you may choose a base process that start for any user session. For inf loop, why does it reconnect? if to change driver or any attribute udev know about it, then use that attribute in udev matching condition.  Whatever is the case, you may `touch` a file and use it as time stamp, your script should check that file age on the start if it is new (ex: <30sec) skip the script.

Comment: @user.dz Thank you very much once more. Thanks to your advice I was able to create a wrapper script that solves both remaining issues. As to why it reconnects and whether this is detectable by udev, I do not know yet.  That will require further testing.

Comment: FYI, you can use `RUN+="/usr/local/bin/a2dp-wrapper.sh $attr{name}"` to pass the actual device name to the program if you want this to work for other device names. That would also the [Don’t Repeat Yourself](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) principle.

Comment: @DavidFoerster Good point. Thank you. I replaced it.

Comment: @DavidFoerster I have added a (rather ugly) version that should cover all devices that behave similar enough. Further enquiry may warrant a new thread, but I think I will refrain from that until I have at least one more device to test it on.

Comment: Nice man,  Interesting, My script is inspired many nerds to run it automatically. such a lazy people :)

Answer (score 0):

I found a (I think easier and also Wayland-compatible) way to do this with `systemctl`.

The udev rule would be the same as the OP's answer:

```
ACTION=="add", SUBSYSTEM=="input" ATTR{name}=="00:22:37:3D:DA:50" RUN+="/usr/local/bin/a2dp-wrapper.sh $attr{name}"
```

`usr/local/bin/a2dp-wrapper.sh` would be:

```
#!/bin/bash
MAC=$1
MACMOD=$(echo $MAC | sed 's/:/_/g')
PID=$(pgrep pulseaudio)
USER=$(grep -z USER= /proc/$PID/environ | sed 's/.*=//')

if pactl list sinks short | grep "bluez_sink\.$MACMOD.*SUSPENDED" 
    then
    systemctl --machine=$USER@.host --user --now start /usr/local/bin/a2dp_2.py $MAC
fi
```

And the appropriate systemd service file in `~/.config/systemd/user/hdmi_sound_toggle.service` is:

```
[Unit]
Description=Runs /usr/local/bin/a2dp_2.py
  
[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/hdmi_sound_toggle.py
```