# Need to repeat pairing to connect bluetooth headphones on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: sound, bluetooth, pulseaudio, alsa, headphones

Question/Problem: I am trying to figure out how I can easily and automatically connect my headphones **without** always having to activate pairing mode.

Base setup: Ubuntu 18.04 with following two lines appended to /etc/bluetooth/main.conf:

```
AutoEnable=true
Disable=Headset
```

(based on [Bluetooth speaker: preferred mode "High fidelity playback" (A2DP) is not getting saved](https://askubuntu.com/questions/319871/bluetooth-speaker-preferred-mode-high-fidelity-playback-a2dp-is-not-getting))

My issue is as follows:
I am able to connect my bluetooth headphones (Sony WH-1000XM2), but I can **only** do so, when the headphones are in **pairing mode** (on the specific headphones this is activated by pressing the power button for a longer time).

When the headphones are activated but **not** in pairing mode, I am able to see the headphones in the Ubuntu Bluetooth menu. However, after pressing the "Connection" On/Off slider button, the slider indicator shows status "On" only for a few seconds and then automatically returns to "Off".

Removing and re-pairing the headphones does not solve the issue.

Answer (score 2):

I use Blueman `sudo apt install blueman`  Once I turn on my headset, I right click on the headset in Blueman and check audio profile, set it to off, then disconnect, connect and then set audio profile to A2DP in Blueman.

It isn't the best fix as there is likely a bug somewhere in bluez or pulseaudio

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I was hoping to find a fix for a smoother user experience, rather than always executing such sequence of actions manually. Let's hope for a fix in the future.

Comment: Maybe something like https://askubuntu.com/a/912838/300665 would work

Answer (score 2):

For Ubuntu 20.4, uncomment the line `#Name = BlueZ` found in `/etc/bluetooth/main.conf`.

Found this fix in a comment by cipricus in https://askubuntu.com/a/912838/300665.

Here is also a link to a guide that might resolve it if that did not fix the issue, https://techwiser.com/fix-bluetooth-device-doesnt-auto-connect-in-linux/.